# Half- life of Radon

Tags: radiation, half-life

If there is increase in the pressure of a container with radon in it , what will happen to the half life of radon?

Comment: Nothing change.

Comment: Interesting question. The others are right, very little will happen. Since Radon decays by emitting an alpha into Polonium, one could guess that increasing the pressure may increase the electron density at the Radon nucleus, thereby lowering the chance of a decay, i.e. the half-life might increase ever so minutely little. Having said that, one would need a detailed quantum mechanical calculation to say for sure which way the effect goes. The resulting changes will be extremely small, either way.

Comment: Is it a theoretical question ? I understood your question as an increase of pressure of a container in common day life or  a laboratory. Else why radon only ?